# Nginx Confiuration for reverse proxy with multiple tomcat instances

Tags: tomcat, nginx, proxy

I am first time working with Nginx.

- I have two servers. SERVER ONE (ip : 1.2.3.4) SERVER TWO (ip :
  5.6.7.8)
- I have Installed nginx on SERVER ONE and Tomcat on SERVER TWO.
- I have successfully configured tomcat to run on different port. My
  tomcat is running on following ports.

  5.6.7.8:8080
  5.6.7.8:8081
  5.6.7.8:8082
- I have also deployed my war file on tomcat(each of the instance).
- I have configured my nginx as follows
- created a default.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d
- Made changes to the file according the following link [Nginx Configuration](https://vpsineu.com/blog/how-to-set-up-tomcat-8-with-nginx-reverse-proxy-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/)

  ```
  server {
          listen 80 default_server;
          listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
      # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
      server_name 1.2.3.4;

      location / {
              proxy_pass http://www.example.com;
              # First attempt to serve request as file, then
              # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
              # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
              # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rule
      }

      location /user/{
              proxy_pass http://5.6.7.8:8080$uri;

              # First attempt to serve request as file, then
              # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
              try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
              # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location
              # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rule
      }
  ```

  }
- The name of War file which I deployed on SERVER TWO is Example.
  which contains a api `/user/login?param1=xyz&param2=abc&param3=mno`
- When I hit the ip **1.2.3.4**, it goes to root(/). I am getting the expected result.I am getting the example.com page.
- **But when I hit 1.2.3.4/user**, I am getting 404 not found.
  I was expecting that my api will be called and I will get the result.
- To check whether my api is working or not if I hit
   **5.6.7.8:8080/Example//user/login?param1=xyz&param2=abc&param3=mno**. I am getting the correct json result which I was expecting.
- And this same result I am expecting when I hit **1.2.3.4/user**.But I am getting 404.

**What all things I have to change in order to get the result when I hit 1.2.3.4/user**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem was the try_files I commented the try files and every thing is working correctly.